# Chose browser open url in android studio

Tags: android, url

I have a link url https://www.google.com.vn/

I want when click link url I can check if my device installed chrome it will always open url with chomre else it will open url with default browser ( not show dialog to chose chrome or internet brower...)
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to get the list of activities which can handle your intent and then use `Intent.setComponent()` to explicitly select the application that you want to launch

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
   PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```